# Which method is better for performance when using MongoTemplate? count(), exists(), findOne()

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm using Java and native MongoDB driver for creating an application. I want to ensure that one record with a specific condition is exists or not.

I've checked similar questions that count() is better than findOne() when the limit(1).

What about exists method? Assuming that query would be the same, and this method will be called every hour.

```
mongoTemplate.count(query, "collectionName")
```

```
monogoTemplate.exists(query, "collectionName")
```

```
mongoTemplate.findOne(query, class, "collectionName")
```

### Edit

To add more information according to @prasad_'s comment,
query that I used is using an indexed field.

Comment: It mostly depends upon the query filter. Having index on the fields used in the filter can improve the performance of the query.

Comment: @prasad_ I added additional information about query that I made. I use indexed field for querying

Comment: You can try the three queries you have and see how they perform - you can generate a _query plan_ and check which performs better. In general, this helps if you are working with a large data sets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) , I've checked all the method and its implementation code, I noticed that count and exists method using the same method inside which means no needs to compare. 

Plus, I check performance via query plan and count() was better than findOne() in my case. Thanks for your help!